# Controller not receiver parameter passed by ajax POST in .Net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, parameters, null, routes

I want to make an ajax  shopping cart, the GetCarts and AddCart all working, but the RemoveRow not
receiver the parameter "strms". When alert(strms) in removeRow(strms) js function, it show right value
of the book id (equal 8). But in the CartController/RemoveRow debug, the strms value is NULL.
I think it's can be a problem with the routing, but I think my route configs are right!
Please help me.

The view is _Layout.cshtml, which contain js code
The controller is CartController

My RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Sach", action = "Detail", id = "7" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
       "Cart",
       "{controller}/{category}/{ms}/{sl}",
        new { controller = "Cart", action = "AddCart", ms = UrlParameter.Optional, sl = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
        routes.MapRoute(
     "CartRemoveRow",
     "{controller}/{action}/{ms}",
      new { controller = "Cart", action = "RemoveRow", ms = UrlParameter.Optional });

    }
}
```

CartController.cs

```
 public class CartController : Controller
{
    List<CartItem> listCart;
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetCarts()
    {
        listCart = Cart.getCart(Session);
        return PartialView("Cart", listCart);
    }

    public void AddCart(string ms, string sl) {

        int masach = int.Parse(ms);
        int soluong = int.Parse(sl);
        Cart.AddCart(masach, soluong, Session);
        //return PartialView("Default");
    }
    public void RemoveRow(string strms)
    {
        int ms1 = int.Parse(strms);
        var sach = new Sach() { MaSach = ms1 };
        Cart.removeCart(sach, true);
    }

}
```

Ajax js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showCart() {
        // alert("1");
        //Load content from CartController
        $(function () {
            //alert("2");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCarts", "Cart")',
                success: function (data) {
                    var result = data;                       
                    $('#myCart').html(result);
                    //alert($('#myCart').html());

                }
            });
        });
        $("#myCart").modal('show');
    }       

    function addCart(ms, sl) {            
        var masach = [];
        masach.push(ms);
        masach.push(sl);            
        // alert(masach);
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("AddCart", "Cart")/'+ms+'/'+ $("#soluong").val(),                    
                success: function (data) {
                    showCart();                        
                }
            });
            return false;
        });         
    }

    function removeRow(strms){          
        $(function () {
           // alert(strms);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("RemoveRow", "Cart")/' + strms,
                success: function (data) {
                    showCart();
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename the javascript variable: "strms" to "ms" and then send it, because in your route "CartRemoveRow" you will receive a variable declared with the name "ms" not "strms".
And of course, in your controller, rename the parameter in the method "RemoveRow" to "ms".

Or more short, change your route to accept "strms":

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "CartRemoveRow",
    "{controller}/{action}/{strms}",
    new { controller = "Cart", action = "RemoveRow", strms = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try passing the parameter in the data property, I have multiple examples but not at home right now.

```
 function removeRow(this_strms){          
    $(function () {
       // alert(strms);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("RemoveRow", "Cart")',
            data: { strms: this_strms},
            success: function (data) {
                showCart();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I normally pass C# objects/classes as parameters like this

```
public void RemoveRow(CartObject strms)
{
    int ms1 = strms.ms1;
    var sach = new Sach() { MaSach = ms1 };
    Cart.removeCart(sach, true);
}
```

in JS i do something like this

```
var thisCartObject= {
  ms1: 1,
  otherproperty: 0.4,
  otherproperty2: "Description"
};


 function removeRow(thisCartObject){          
    $(function () {
       // alert(strms);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("RemoveRow", "Cart")',
            data: JSON.stringify({ strms: thisCartObject}),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                showCart();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

If you are going to try this, try without! your custom route defined in the RegisterRoutes class first.